# How to use processBuilder in Java to execute an exe with arguments in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

This is the code I've been using:

```
            ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\path\\to\\exe\\my_exe.exe ",
                "my_exe.exe", "/removeDrive", "driveLocation");
            process.start();
```

All this seems to do is run the exe, but I can't get it to run the command I want.

The command in CMD would be:

```
C:\users\path\to\exe>my_exe.exe /removeDrive driveLocation
```

The command works fine in windows Command Prompt

Comment: Have you tried `new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\path\\to\\exe\\my_exe.exe", "/removeDrive", "driveLocation")`?

Comment: That seems to just open the exe also.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same thing:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd", "/c", "path/to/exe.exe", 
        "/removeDrive", "driveLocation");
pb.start();
```

Or if you don't need output:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C my_exe.exe /removeDrive driveLocation");
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `cmd` and `/c`?

Comment: CMD is windows command prompt and /c carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates.

Comment: Does `getRuntime().exec()` need to specify the directory?

Comment: Yes: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C C:/patch/to/exe/my_exe.exe /removeDrive driveLocation"); or Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C C:\\Users\\path\\to\\exe\\my_exe.exe /removeDrive driveLocation");

Comment: If the path to the exe is available in the `PATH` system-variable, you can omit it - `cmd` uses `PATH` to resolve the location.